# Android fill spinner dynamically

Tags: android

if I have two spinner and add to first spinner as:

```
    int pos=0;
    spinner1 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
    List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
    list.add("list 1");
    list.add("list 2");
    list.add("list 3");
    ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
        android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, list);
    dataAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    spinner1.setAdapter(dataAdapter);
    spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {
     @Override
     public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parentView, View selectedItemView, int   position, long id) {
        pos=position;
      }

      @Override
      public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parentView) {
      }

});
```

And now I want to fill the second spinner Based on the position of first spinner How do I do that?

e.g.

if pos->0 second spinner Contains {A,B,C}

if pos->1 second spinner Contains {D,E,F}

... etc.

thanks in advance...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `onItemSelected(...)`, change the adapter of the second spinner based on the position of the first. You should be able to reuse some of your code to accomplish this.